# How to set a variable to a AJAX response data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, scope

I am using jQuery and I have the following code:

```
var result = [];

if ( some_condition ) {
  result = [...]
} else {
  $.ajax({
    url:      some_url,
    data:     some_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:  function(data) {
      items = data
    }
  });

  result = items
}

// Playing with the 'result' variable...
```

The above code generates the error "`items is not defined`" when `some_condition` is `false` (I think it happens because the variable scope is not correct).

I would like to set the `result` variable to the AJAX response data but I don't know how to solve the problem.

---

*Note*: I am trying to do that because I would like to use the `result` variable *outside* the `if ... else` statement (that is, *after* the `if ... else` statement in the above code).

Comment: Asynchronous callbacks, look into it.

Comment: You have to declare var items same as variable result before condition

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @alex - By setting the `async: false` option for the `$.ajax` makes it to work, but is the `async: false` deprecated?

Comment: @user12882 No, but if you want to lock your users' browsers you can try it.

Answer (score 12):

Simply make the ajax function no async

```
var result = [];

if ( some_condition ) {
  result = [...]
} else {
    $.ajax({
    url:      some_url,
    data:     some_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false, 
    success:  function(data) {
        items = data
    }
    });
   result = items
}
```

Comment: It means that you can't do anything else until the request is done, any other operations below the ajax call will be stopped until it finish

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

Since you are calling it async, you should assign it in your callback function

```
var result = []; 


if ( some_condition ) {
  result = [...]
} else {
  $.ajax({
    url:      some_url,
    data:     some_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:  function(data) {
      result = data;
      validateResult(result);
    }
  });
}
```

And for your better understanding.

Your result array is a global variable.

1. Initially its an array with length = 0;
2. You call your ajax function.
3. The length of result array is still 0.
4. Ajax call completes and success function is executed.
5. In success function you assign result to your response data.
6. Now the length of result array is not zero any more .
7. Globally the value is updated.
8. You can use result array anywhere in your code

Comment: I would like to use the `result` variable outside the `if ... else` statement. Still with you code that is not possible.

Comment: It should be possible, you just need to make sure that the callback has executed (AJAX completed) before trying to reference `result`.

Comment: since result is a global variable, you can still refer to it

Comment: @Matt Stone - How "to make sure that the callback has executed (AJAX completed) before trying to reference `result`"? I tried (as alex suggested in a previous comment) to set `async: false` option for the `$.ajax` and it works... but is the `async: false` deprecated?

Comment: Call the function which do you logic inside your success function. Like validateResult in here.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that you are meaning?

Comment: Sure. May i know what you would like to do with your result variable. Is it some checking or adding elements or something?

Comment: Of course. I have to add some elements and even execute some checking.

Comment: Replace validateResult(result); in my code with your Function Call.

Comment: Maybe I was not so clear: I am trying to do that because I would like to use the `result` variable *outside* the `if ... else` statement (that is, *after* the `if ... else` code posted in the question).

Comment: I seen your update. In steps 4 and 5 it does *not* set the `result` so that I can use that variable "outside" the `if ... else` statement / context. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Yes. Before step 5 complete, result array still has length zero. step 5 is an asynchronous callback, which means the rest of the code is still running.

Comment: May i see the function that you want to execute? may be in jsfiddle or something

Comment: I do not have any relevant function to be executed. I just need to use the `result` variable after in the code, for example: `result.pop()` and `result.push(...)`.